# Which C crypto framework do you recommend for symmetric & asymmetric cryptography?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography

Which C crypto framework do you recommend for symmetric & asymmetric cryptography?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSSL is great and fast.  If that doesn't work for you, you can also consider [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) (if C++ is ok) or [PolarSSL](http://polarssl.org/).

Answer (score 3):

The OpenSSL library is the largest and most widely used collection of cryptographic primitives.